# Why is FilteredTextBoxExtender causing Unable to get property 'UI' of undefined or null reference error?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I added the following to a web page:

```
 <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender runat="server" FilterType="Numbers"
      TargetControlID="txtCompanyID" ID="ftbe1">
 </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

There is a ScriptManager on the page and the Ajax Control Toolit is registered.

First off, I was getting Cannot resolve symbol 'ID' in VS2010. I did Ctrl-Shft-Alt-8 to get rid of this error.

When I try to load the page, all I get is this:

JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'UI' of undefined or null reference

And this line is highlighted:

```
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.FilteredTextBoxBehavior {
    "FilterType":2,
    "id":"MainContent_ftbe1"
}, null, null, $get("MainContent_txtCompanyID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following does not already exist in your page, try adding it to your page source - probably needs to be right after the control or after your existing script manager:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ajaxScriptManager" EnablePartialRendering="true" CombineScripts="false" />
```

If it already exists, the CombineScripts attribute probably is set to true, and you should set it to false. Also make sure your @PAGE directive does not have Trace="true" - if so, set it to false also and then you can actually leave CombineScripts attribute on the Ajax Script Manager to true.